# Joomla menu ordering not saved in table

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am using Joomla 2.5 i have group of menus i ordered the menu in admin but it does not get saved in back end

In menu table ordering is stored as 0 only

Where the order of the menu is stored

Comment: Check lft and rgt column of menu table for ordering.

Comment: @irfan but it shows different values. I want to know  where is the ordering column in admin get saved in table

Comment: It is never saved and if it is not empty you will get big problems later. lft is the field used for ordering since menus are a nested set.

Answer (score 1):

Try entering a number in one of the order fields and hit the little save button. If all numbers are 0 it doesn't get saved. It's kind of a bug I think.

Comment: As Irfan already wrote, the ordering isn't saved in the _ordering_ column. It's saved in the _lft_ column. The _ordering_ column isn't used anymore, it's a left over and is removed with Joomla! 3.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost positive the number column for ordering hasn't worked for a while.
If you instead click the blue arrows found between the "Status" and "Ordering" columns and move them as you wish, this will save the ordering of the menu items.

Answer (score -1):

I have seen this problem before when hidden menu items, such as those that have been trashed, are causing something of a problem.

Clear the trashed in menu manager and then try rebuild, this should allow you to better manage the order of your menu items.